# Javascript class instance method does not work with onClick callback event in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-component

I was trying to update my state variable when the button is clicked on my page.
But I see that I cannot use react class component methods. Here is the minimum reproducible example.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Name extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            name : "Farhan Ahmed"
        }
    }
    clickMe() {
        this.setState({
            name:"Ahmed Farhan"
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
                <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.clickMe}>Change Text</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Name
```

Error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setState')
```

But when I replace the same with arrow function it works for me.

My question is why didn't regular class method work in this case why do I need to replace the same with arrow function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the docs found here https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html this error is explained, along with possible solutions. If you're not using the experimental "public class fields syntax" the docs refer to, you can either `bind` your function, or use an arrow function:

**With bind**

`onClick={this.clickMe.bind(this)}`

**Arrow function**

`onClick={() => this.clickMe()}`

These are the most common (that I've seen personally), but the docs provide more solutions as well.

**Edit**

Someone pointed out that OP is asking "why", not necessarily "how do I fix it?" So from the docs linked above:

> You have to be careful about the meaning of `this` in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind `this.handleClick` and pass it to `onClick`, `this` will be undefined when the function is actually called.

> This is not React-specific behavior; it is a part of how functions work in JavaScript. Generally, if you refer to a method without () after it, such as `onClick={this.handleClick}`, you should bind that method.

Comment: @MattU I don't understand, why do I need to explicitly bind this keyword, this keword inside the JS classes methods are totally allowed

Answer (score 0):

When you try to access `this` keyword without binding the function, `this` keyword is undefined. so, you need to either bind that function in constructor or use an arrow function syntax which ensures `this` is bound within that function.
You can check  documentation of [bind method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) method and [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Button is not clicked, but function will run while the component is rendering.

```
onClick={this.clickMe}
```

And this;

```
onClick={() => this.clickMe}
```

Function only works when the buttons are clicked.

Read this: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/responding-to-events